# Subquery returns more than 1 row using REPLACE

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to replace a word into a subquery that get all books that have the same author. This is the query:

```
SELECT REPLACE((SELECT LOWER(b.title) 
FROM books b 
WHERE b.author_id = a.id), 'wordReplace', '') 
FROM authors a;
```

But the response is:

> Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

I try using too:

```
SELECT REPLACE((SELECT LOWER(b.title) FROM books b WHERE b.author_id IN(SELECT a.id FROM authors a)), 'wordReplace', '') 
FROM authors a;
```

Please help!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Why are you even using a subquery to begin with?  It looks completely unnecessary and like it's the cause of your problems.

Comment: The problem is that SUBQUERY returns more than 1 row. Anyway - code is bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that community don't like this questions, but i want to help.

Pls, dont use subquery if it's not necessary (mostly it's a bad decision)

Instead of using

```
SELECT REPLACE
(
    (SELECT LOWER(b.title) FROM books b WHERE b.author_id = a.id), 'wordReplace', ''
) 
FROM authors a;
```

You should write this

```
SELECT REPLACE(LOWER(b.title), 'wordReplace', '')
FROM books b
INNER JOIN authors a ON b.author_id = a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to provide more information , but I think you are trying to do this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(LOWER(b.title), 'wordReplace', '')  
FROM authors a
join books b  
  on b.author_id = a.id;
```

or you might wanna use `left join`, if you wanna show authors with no book